# What does it mean by Object [ ]

Tags: java, object

I am sorry if this question is silly question, but I have hard time to understand the usage of Object []. I want to know what does below method really return. because it is enveloped as an object. Why i m asking this because i want to replace this method with other method to integrate with other module.

What I understand it would return list of Value Object? But what is this Object[] really means?

Thank you soo much.

```
public Object[] generateNewGreedySolution(int startingPoint) {
    if (startingPoint == -1) {
        startingPoint = new Random().nextInt(ins.getDimension() + 1);
    }

    //Solution s = new Solution(problem);
    Object[] values = new Object[ins.getDimension()];

    List<Integer> cities = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ins.getDimension(); i++) {
        if ((i + 1) != startingPoint) {
            cities.add(i + 1);
        }
    }

    values[0] = startingPoint;
    for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
        double minCost = -1;
        int index = -1;

        for (int j = 0; j < cities.size(); j++) {
            double distance = ins.getDistance(startingPoint, cities.get(j));

            if (distance < minCost || minCost == -1) {
                minCost = distance;
                index = j;
            }
        }

        values[i] = cities.get(index);
        startingPoint = cities.get(index);

        cities.remove(index);
    }

    return values;
}
```

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: "what is this Object[] really means". Nothing special, it means same as any other array i.e. String[], Integer[] etc. A contiguos memory allocation of a specific type.

Comment: @Lokesh not like that. An `Object[]` is an array that can hold anything that is not a primitive. It contain a `String`, an `Integer`, even another `Object[]` inside it.

Comment: Tq. Jon.yea i think i better learn better about an arrays too.  actually, what i m trying to understand here is how does array of object [] really work..  ?i seem cant visualize it.. should i change the question? But i dont know how to ask..thats y i give about example..

Comment: @luiggi oh.. now i have some insight about it . it is like an array of object " object[] " could hold different datatype in same array?

Comment: @Jasmin yes, it can hold any kind of object inside it: `String`, Integer`, `MyCustomClass`, even arrays, because an array is an `Object`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza , thanks. clear explanation. But this kind of array make me confuse.. fuh... never work with this array before.

Comment: Not sure who designed this algorithm, but surely that person doesn't know what is doing, because all the elements in that `Object[] values` are `Integer`, so it could easily be an `Integer[] values` or even better, an `int[] values`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your `generateNewGreedySolution` method returns an array of `Object` Type

In the 5th line you are doing

```
Object[] values = new Object[ins.getDimension()];
```

So here values is an object array and hence you are returing the same.

If you are confused of what to return in methods then please note that if your method signaure is int then you should return int,if your method signature is String then you should return String.

Here your method return type is Object[] and so you are returning values

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, i was about to say it.

Comment: Thanks Jquery, it return an array of Object type = where the object here is value?

Answer (score 1):

*Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has Object as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class.*

from: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Meaning that you are able to use an array of the type `Object` to return a collection of just about every class object. For example you could have the object with index 0 be an `Integer` another one being a `String`.

But since "only" all the classes are inherited, you need to notice that primitives are NOT. What I mean with that is that there is for example a difference between `int` (primitive) and an `java.lang.Integer` (which is inherited from said `Object` and has an `int` member variable, but can also point to `null`).